# Perl: Pattern Match using two arrays and mapping

Tags: perl

Below is the script using for pattern match. Can anyone help me in increasing the efficiency of this code. Its taking longer time when I use larger files. I am not that much aware of using hash.Please improve the below mentioned code and update.

```
open(OUT,"> Correct.txt");
open(ERR,"> ERROR_Report.txt");
open(IN, "File1.txt");
my @values = <IN>;
close IN;
$flag=0;
$count=0;
open(IN, "File2.txt");
my @verify = <IN>;
close IN;

foreach my $ver(@verify){
    foreach my $rep(@values){
        if ($ver =~ /$rep/){
            $flag=1;
            $count++;
        }
    }

    if($flag==1){
        print OUT "$ver";
        $flag=0;
    }
    else{
        print ERR "$ver";
    }
}

print OUT "Total Count:$count";
```

Please help me.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: *Always* `use strict; use warnings;`! (And slightly OT; a good read: http://eev.ee/blog/2011/04/13/perl-worst-practices )

Comment: What I wonder is why an array of "rep"s is called `@values`?

Comment: If you're trying to lines common to both files, and lines that are in one file but not in the other, have you tried using the Unix comm(1) [http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm] command?

Comment: I am using this script in windows platform

Comment: Gotcha. Is one file consistently larger than the other?

Comment: Yes one file size can be more than 10 Mb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compiling num_verify * num_values regex patterns even though you only have num_values different patterns.

```
my @rep_regexps = map { qr/$_/ } @values;

for my $ver (@verify) {
    for my $rep_regexp (@rep_regexps) {
        if ($ver =~ /$rep_regexp/) {
            $flag = 1;
            ++$count;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

If no two of the regexps you read from `File1.txt` can match overlapping parts of any of the strings you read from `File2.txt`, you can optimize the above further.

```
my $reps_pattern = join '|', @values;
my $reps_regexp = qr/$reps_pattern/;

for my $ver (@verify) {
     while ($ver =~ /$reps_regexp/g) {
         $flag = 1;
         ++$count;
    }

    ...
}
```

If no two of the regexps you read from `File1.txt` can match anyof the strings you read from `File2.txt`, you can optimize the above further.

```
my $reps_pattern = join '|', @values;
my $reps_regexp = qr/$reps_pattern/;

for my $ver (@verify) {
     if ($ver =~ /$reps_regexp/) {
         $flag = 1;
         ++$count;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't see how hashing could be used here.

Comment: I mean to say the efficiency regarding speed, even though the file size is more than 10 Mb.

Comment: There's nothing to hash, really. Hashing is only appropriate in certain scenarios. The only thing I can think of is if your patterns aren't patterns, i.e. if you're doing full string matches between the two files.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could explain more in general about what you are trying to accomplish. I think this summarizes it: You have a "verify" file containing lines and a "values" file containing patterns; if any given pattern of "values" is found in "verify", print the original line to output. If the pattern is not found, print the original line to error.

What do you want "total count" to mean? Right now it means the total number of patterns in "values" matched, not the total number of lines in "verify" matched. Part of your efficiency problem is that you keep checking for patterns after a line has already matched. Is this by design or is it an error we can correct?

Are you truly doing a pattern match, or a simple line comparison? The latter opens up some different options on how we can approach this. Is "verify" the 10MB file or "values"? In general, you should choose the larger file as the "driving" input, and only read the non-driving input into memory.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(OUT, '>', 'Correct.txt')
  or die "unable to open Correct.txt for writing: $!\n";
open(ERR, '>', 'ERROR_Report.txt')
  or die "unable to open ERROR_Report.txt for writing: $!\n";

# File1.txt contains patterns for matching
open(PATTERNS, '<', 'File1.txt')
  or die "unable to open File1.txt for reading: $!\n";

# Read in patterns and remove trailing CRLF
chomp(my @patterns = <PATTERNS>);
my $pattern = join '|', @patterns;
# Compute a single regex with all the patterns
my $pattern_re = qr/$pattern/;

close(PATTERNS);

# File2.txt contains lines to check for patterns
open(LINES, '<', 'File2.txt')
  or die "unable to open File2.txt for reading: $!\n";

my $count = 0;
while (my $line = <LINES>) {
  # Remove trailing CRLF
  chomp;

  if ($line =~ $pattern_re) {
    print OUT $line."\r\n";
    $count++;
  }
  else {
    print ERR $line."\r\n";
  }
}

close(LINES);

print OUT "Total matching lines: $count\r\n";
```